# Accessing parent of a SimpleXML element results in "Array"

Tags: php, xpath, simplexml

Hello I have an XML code like this:

```
<article>
  <title><![CDATA[IEEE Transactions on]]></title>
  <articleinfo>
    <articleseqnum>13</articleseqnum>
    <idamsid>0b0000648011bcfb</idamsid>
.............
```

I try to access the parent of an element with SimpleXML like this:

```
$xmlUrl = "example.xml"; // XML feed file/URL

$xmlStr = file_get_contents($xmlUrl);

$xmlObj = simplexml_load_string($xmlStr);

$titles = $xmlObj->xpath("//title");

foreach ($titles as $title)
{
   $parent_title = $title->xpath("parent::*");

   echo "Parent element of title: ". $parent_title."</br>";

}
```

But I take this result:

```
Parent element of title: Array
```

Instead of

```
Parent element of title: article
```

What is maybe the problem? Thank you in advance!

Comment: `->xpath()` returns always an array - even if it returns one node only.

Comment: hmmm. Ok. But how can I return the desired result?

Comment: Try using: `name(parent::*)` or the equivalent and shorter: `name(..)`

Comment: Hello my friend? How to use them? $parent_title = $title....? if you can give me a hand. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the first element out of the ->xpath() result array, and call getName() on it. (inside the loop)

```
$parent_title = $title->xpath("parent::*");
if ($parent_title) {
    echo "Parent element of title: ", $parent_title[0]->getName(), "</br>\n";
}
```

Comment: It's exactly what I needed! Thanks my friend!!